# https domain is redirect to https://localhost using vhost xampp in Mac

Tags: php, macos, https, xampp, vhosts

When try to open https://blog.r3ciprocity.com it redirect to https://localhost I don't know what configuration I missed.
Here is my configuration file

#httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs"
    <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
    # Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted    
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

     <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Atdrive/blog_r3ciprocity"
        ServerName blog.r3ciprocity.com
        ServerAlias blog.r3ciprocity.com
     </VirtualHost>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName blog.r3ciprocity.com
        ServerAlias blog.r3ciprocity.com
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile "etc/ssl.crt/server.crt" 
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "etc/ssl.key/server.key"
        DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Atdrive/blog_r3ciprocity"
        <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Atdrive/blog_r3ciprocity">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
        # Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted 
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

#/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1 blog.r3ciprocity.com
```